# Elisp: simple function to split window and move cursor to new window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I feel dumb posting this but I really have no idea why this function doesn't compile:

```
(defun dc/split-window-below-and-move-cursor ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-below)
  (other-window 1))
```

Am I overlooking something super obvious?

Here's the error message:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: split-window-below
```

Update: So I tried it in another file (on a fresh Emacs session) and it worked fine. (Taking out `progn` and putting in `(interactive)` didn't resolve it either - I've updated the code above to reflect this change.)

Update 2: Okay, this is just silly.  The following code works fine but I still can't get the `defun` code above to work.  Would still be very curious to understand what's causing this behavior, if anyone has ideas.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s--") (lambda() (interactive) (split-window-below) (other-window 1)))
```

Comment: For future question: Emacs has its own site in the stackexchange network now ( http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `progn`, but you need `interactive`:

```lisp
(defun dc/split-window-below-and-move-cursor ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-below)
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: unfortunately, no dice.  the  lambda version - which is what I initially had in my `init` file - is working fine.  but the reason for moving to an explicit function was for documentation purposes (i.e., right now, when I invoke the help/describe-key command, I see an ugly lambda expression in place of a definition).

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "s--") 'dc/split-window-below-and-move-cursor)` works for me

Comment: well...my emacs just totally blew up.  (windows closing themselves randomly, etc.; it continued after I ran via `emacs -q`.)  the installation of emacs 24 seems to have corrupted things.  thanks anyways for trying.